# Como fechar tela splash?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Desenvolvi uma tela de *splash* para minha aplicação. Está funcionando perfeitamente, ele abre e direciona para o `Form2`. Porém percebi que ao fechar o `Form2`, tenho que parar de depurar pelo Visual Studio, pois parece que o *splash* fica ativo. Usei o seguinte código abaixo no método `Timer1`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(progressBar1.Value < 100){
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                this.Visible = false;
                Form1 direcionar = new Form1();
                direcionar.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

A minha preocupação é que ao instalar o app em outro computador, o splash permanecerá ativo na memória, em caso positivo, como eu faria para que ao fechar a app, o splash também fosse encerrado e não apenas invisível.

Veja a imagem abaixo. Fechei a app, mas continua depurando.

[image: SS]

Comment: é por que a sua tela Splash está apenas oculta, você não a fechou. Você pode fechar a tela Splash [ .close() ] no evento load do seu Form2.

Comment: Oi Iago. Tentei da forma como vc falou, mas mesmo assim o problema continua.

Comment: faz o seguinte então: use a Application.Exit() no evento Close do seu Form2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só dar um `this.Close()` (partindo do princípio que a tela de *splash* é o `this`) no momento que achar que deve. O método [`Close()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_Close) coloca o formulário à disposição para ser removido da memória. Não precisa mais nada. Se esta variável não for mais referenciada em outros lugares, no momento adequado, o *garbage colletor* liberará todos recursos que foram alocados para ele. O .NET tem a memória gerenciada e você não precisa se preocupar com essas coisas, basta usar direito: garantir que o recurso foi encerrado como mostrado acima e não ter mais referências a ele que podem mantê-lo vivo mesmo que não sendo mostrado. Ficaria algo assim:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (progressBar1.Value < 100){
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 2;
    } else {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        this.Close();
        var direcionar = new Form1(); //isto provavelmente não pode estar aqui.
        direcionar.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Splash.cs).

Mas só isto provavelmente não vai resolver o consumo de memória porque este objeto ficará ativo impedindo de ser coletado. Além disto, não me lembro das consequências, mas se você encerrar um formulário que criou outro ou vai dar erro ou vai manter o objeto ativo.

A forma como está construindo a aplicação a *splash screen* será sua tela principal e nunca será destruída de fato ou será destruída encerrando a aplicação. Ou você inverte esta situação, ou seja, cria um formulário principal  e chame temporariamente a *splash screen* dentro deste formulário ou o que eu faria é separar os dois formulários, algo assim (simplificadamente falando):

```
Application.Run(new SplashForm());
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

Uma [resposta no SO com uma outra forma de fazer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393870/221800) o mesmo. O .NET já tem infraestrutura para realizar a tarefa.

Comment: Certo. Nesse caso se houver um botão de sair, correto? Porém o que tenho é uma app de uma só tela, onde não uso menu. Pelo que entendi, o .Net automaticamente irá fechar o splash assim que a app for fechada?

Comment: Tela de *splash* é uma tela que fica aberta por alguns momentos, então não entendo esta sua dúvida. Você é responsável por fechá-la quando quiser. Por evento de um botão, por um tempo determinado, ou pelo fim de determinadas operações. Talvez o seu problema seja outro, mas sua pergunta não dá indicação disto. Ou você nem tem uma tela de *splash* e acha que tem.

Comment: Vamos lá bigown. Acho que não fui claro na minha dúvida. Criei um sistema de agendamento do qual só tem uma tela. Esse sistema tem uma tela de splash do qual direciona para outra tela. Quando estou no Visual Studio e clico em depurar o programa, a tela de splash aparece corretamente e direciona para o sistema. Até aqui tudo OK. Porém ao fechar a app, percebo que tenho que parar a depuração pelo VS também, o que não ocorria antes de colocar o splash. Logo percebo que o splash parece continuar ativo colocando esse comando this.Visible = false;.

Comment: O que gostaria de saber se ao executar essa app em outro computador, isso poderá ocorrer, ou seja, o splash permanecer ativo na memória mesmo fechando a app. Se sim, como faria para resolver esse problema.

Comment: Isso não ajudou muito porque você repetiu o que você escreveu na pergunta e não acrescentou nenhuma informação nova. Eu não consigo ajudar mais só com esse trecho de código. Mas a solução é a que dei na resposta. Tem que fechar o formulário, não pode ser esconder.

Comment: Certo. Tem razão. Editei o código na minha pergunta. O splash permanece ativo por alguns segundos, depois fecha e direciona pra o sistema. Até aqui tudo OK. Porém parece que ele permanece ativo, pois mesmo fechando a app,  tenho que parar a depuração pelo VS.

Comment: Bigown, coloquei a imagem na minha pergunta. Mesmo fechando a app, a depuração continua ativa depois que coloquei o splash. Veja se a imagem ajuda na minha dúvida.

Comment: Isto não ajuda nada. Eu melhorei a resposta mas ainda parece haver problema estrutural em toda a aplicação. Você não deveria atrelar a criação da tela da aplicação dentro da tela de *splash*, elas não têm relação. Deveria fazer a tela de *splash* e só quando ela terminar sua execução é que deveria criar um formulário novo, de forma isolada. O seu problema não está só neste trecho.

Comment: Certo bigown. Tentei usar o .Close(), porém o Form1 não abre. Fecha também. Você disse que o Form1 direcionar = new Form1(); não pode estar aqui, como eu faria então para direcionar pra esse formulário depois de fechar o splash?

Comment: É o que eu falei, você está com um problema estrutural na aplicação, não é só isto. Há problemas que vão além do que setá neste trecho. Então não tem como eu ajudar mais que isto nesta pergunta. Olha a quantidade de comentários, quando acontece isto, tem alguma coisa errada na pergunta. O comentário acima já dá uma ideia de como resolver. Não dou a solução completa porque não conheço sua aplicação completa.

Comment: Pessoal. A solução que encontrei foi assim que entrei na tela principal, no evento FormClosed, coloquei o código: Application.Exit(); Dessa forma, ao fechar pelo X da janela principal, fecho também a tela de Splash que fica escondida.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderá colocar este codigo "`Application.Exit();`" no evento FormClosed e no FormClosing para matar de vez a sua aplicação do Splash